# Python Inheritance - Call Parent Methods for remainder of call stack

Tags: python

I have an inheritance structure and I want to call parent class methods for the remainder of the call stack after invoking a parent class method with "super".  This this possible?

```
class Parent(object):
    def f(self):
        self.g()

    def g(self):
        self.h()

    def h(self):
       print 1


class Child(Parent):
    def f(self):
        super(Child, self).g()

    def g(self):
        self.h()

    def h(self):
        print 2


c = Child()
c.f()
```

This code outputs "2" because when the super class method "g" calls "h", it invokes the child class method.

I want it to output 1, "h" should also be invoked on the superclass.

Is this possible and if so how can I

Comment: It's _possible_, but it's not the correct solution to your problem. It would be hacky and messy and unreadable. Why would you need to do this? If the child class overrides a method, it makes sense that the child method is called instead of the parent method. If they're not interchangeable, then you (almost certainly) used inheritance wrong.

Comment: How is it possible? You didn't provide an answer

Comment: Of course I didn't provide an answer. I asked you a question, and you didn't provide an answer either.

Comment: Are you trying to write `Parent` so its methods are unaffected by subclass overrides of different methods?

Comment: Yes, wondering if its possible and how.  I'm not evening using this in my code anymore (simplest workaround for my design is to rename h, i.e "h2" in the child class) but I am simply curious.

If its such a flawed design that the inheritance in python explicitly prevents this, then that is helpful to know too.

Comment: I feel like I had a dupe for this, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have methods of `Parent` call public methods of `self` unless you specifically want to use subclass implementations there. Instead, have your public methods delegate to "private" methods:

```
class Parent(object):
    def __f(self):
        self.__g()

    def f(self):
        return self.__f()

    def __g(self):
        self.__h()

    def g(self):
        return self.__g()

    def __h(self):
       print 1

    def h(self):
        return self.__h()
```

Subclasses of `Parent` can then override `f`, `g`, and `h` without affecting the behavior of calls to `super().f()`, `super().g()`, or `super().h()`, and subclasses can use the same technique without interfering with the parent methods due to name mangling.

---

Alternatively, you can have `Parent` call the `Parent` implementations directly:

```
class Parent(object):
    def f(self):
        Parent.g(self)

    def g(self):
        Parent.h(self)

    def h(self):
       print 1
```

Either way, the important thing is not to call `self.some_public_method` unless you actually want to use subclass implementations of `some_public_method`.

Answer (score 0):

When `child` calls the parent class's `g`, `child` does not relinquish its inherent identity as a `Child`: that stays with it, even as it runs through `Parent.g`.  When it invokes `self.h`, the class of `self` is still `Child`, rather than `Parent`, and control passes to `Child.h`.

If you want this to work otherwise, you need to *not* override `Parent.h` with a `Child` method, or make an explicit call to `Parent.h`.  I recommend that you do the first -- very simply if you don't want method `h` overridden, don't override it.  Call the `Child` method `child_h`, for example.